# Cannot get set interval to work?

Tags: javascript, canvas

No matter what I do I cannot get this bit of code to work, the part where you set an interval in the draw method and will call the Loop method 4 times in two seconds, each call displaying a different image. Currently it shows nothing? And the issue is not with an images etc as it works with one image fine. Been at this for 2 days..

```
 function Explosion() //space weapon uses this
{
this.srcX = 0;
this.srcY = 1250;
this.drawX = 0;
this.drawY = 0;
this.width = 70;
this.height = 70;
this.currentFrame = 0;
this.totalFrames = 10;
this.hasHit = false;
this.frame = 0;

}

Explosion.prototype.draw = function()
{

 if(this.hasHit == true && this.frame < 5)
 {

    var t=setTimeout(Explosion.Loop,500);

 }

 if(this.frame == 5)
 {
 clearTimeout(t);
 this.hasHit = false;
  this.frame = 0;
 }



}

Explosion.prototype.Loop = function()
{

ctxExplosion.clearRect ( 0 , 0, canvasWidth , canvasHeight );

if(this.frame == 1)
{

   ctxExplosion.drawImage(spriteImage,this.srcX,this.srcY,this.width,this.height,this.drawX,this.drawY,this.width,this.height);
   frame++;
}

else if(this.frame == 2)
{

    ctxExplosion.drawImage(spriteImage,this.srcX,(this.srcY + 77),this.width,this.height,this.drawX,this.drawY,this.width,this.height);
   frame++;
}

else if(this.frame == 3)
{
  ctxExplosion.drawImage(spriteImage,this.srcX,(this.srcY + 154),this.width,this.height,this.drawX,this.drawY,this.width,this.height);
   frame++;

}

else if(this.frame == 4)
{
  ctxExplosion.drawImage(spriteImage,this.srcX,(this.srcY + 231),this.width,this.height,this.drawX,this.drawY,this.width,this.height);
   frame++;

}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few problems:

1. **`Explosion.Loop` does not exist**; in normal classical languages, your error would be known as "trying to call an instance method as if it were static." What you could do is instead pass `Explosion.prototype.Loop` or `this.Loop`, but that's no good either: JavaScript's `this` is dynamic and you'll end up trying to get and set properties on `window` rather than your object.

   What you need to do is use `this.Loop`, but make sure the `this` isn't lost. On newer browsers, that can be done with `bind`<sup>1</sup>:

   ```
   setTimeout(this.Loop.bind(this), 500);
   ```

   <sup>1</sup> If they're new enough to support `canvas`, they probably support `bind`.
2. **`setTimeout` will only call your function once**; if you want it to be called every half a second rather than only once half a second from now, you'll need to use `setInterval` instead.
3. **Accessing instance variables as if they were local variables.** In several places (for example, `frame` in `Loop`), you're accessing `frame` like this:

   ```
   frame++;
   ```

   Unfortunately, `frame` is not a local variable; it's a property of `this`. Unlike some other languages, you have to explicitly qualify it:

   ```
   this.frame++;
   ```

   As previously mentioned, `frame` is not the only variable with this problem.

Comment: @Kolink: You're right; it was the first one that popped out at me. I've edited my answer to cover a few more problems they had, although I might still be missing some problems.

Comment: if(this.frame <= 4)
{
 setTimeout(this.Loop.bind(this), 500);
}

Still won't work? :/

Comment: @StevenBarrett: There were a few problems I didn't catch initially; see my edited answer and fix those, too. If you still have problems, it might be helpful to see if there are any errors in your console, as those may point to your problem.

Comment: Console shows nothing wrong, right now however all that happens is the browsers slows really fast then freezes. I guess this is to do with the Interval? In action: http://www.taffatech.com/DarkOrbit.html  and the source: http://www.taffatech.com/Source.js

Comment: try: `this.t=setInterval(...` and in your Explosion.prototype.loop after if this.frame=4 `clearInterval(this.t)` You'd still have a problem if you have multiple explosions going on in the same instance of a Explosion object.

Comment: Hmm still just freezing when it explodes..

Source updated: http://www.taffatech.com/Source.js

Comment: @StevenBarrett: `setTimeout` can be cleared with `clearTimeout`. `setInterval` can be cleared with `clearInterval`.

Comment: `while(this.hasHit == true){this.t=setInterval(this.Loop.bind(this), 500);` My gues is that that should be: `if`(this.hasHit === true) You're creating an infinate loop there. Maybe you should put some console.log statements in your program so you can see what it's doing before asking. It'll save you a lot of time. For example `console.log("Going to show the explosing in 5 steps, frame is now:",this.frame)`

Comment: Thanks HMR, now the explosions are happening, any way to make them not flicker...and stop? :)

Comment: @StevenBarrett: They might be flickery because every explosion calls `clearRect`. You'll likely want to synchronize all your explosions so you call `clearRect` and then draw the current frame of every explosion.

Comment: Thanks icktoofay, any idea how to do this? I used request AnimFrame for the ship movement, might this be useful?

Comment: @StevenBarrett: It could be, yes. You'd still use `setTimeout` or `setInterval` or whatever you're using for changing `this.frame`, but you'd move the drawing of all of the explosions into one place.